# If a Knowledge domain cleric casts Identify as a ritual, does anything different happen?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm currently running a Knowledge domain Cleric and I'm wondering is there any other effect involved with casting an Identify spell as a ritual changes what happens with the spell being cast?

Comment: Are you asking if casting Identify as a ritual changes the spell's effects?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Currently it's unclear what you are asking in your question. Are you asking if *identify* is different when cast as a ritual? Or are you asking if casting *identify* as a cleric has some extra effect? Or something else? Please elaborate.

Comment: Do either of the answers answer your question well enough for a green check?

Comment: That will be fine it covers the areas I was wondering about so yes.

Answer (score 7):

The only differences are the casting time, you cannot up-cast the spell, and no spell slots are consumed. From the [rules for ritual casting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals):

> Certain spells have a special tag: ritual. Such a spell can be cast following the normal rules for spellcasting, or the spell can be cast as a ritual. The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to cast than normal. It also doesn't expend a spell slot, which means the ritual version of a spell can't be cast at a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

#### The [*identify*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify) spell has the same effects when cast ritually or with a spell slot

The only difference between casting *identify* as a ritual is that it takes 10 minutes longer to cast, as per the rules for [ritual casting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals):

> Certain spells have a special tag: ritual. Such a spell can be cast following the normal rules for spellcasting, or the spell can be cast as a ritual. **The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to cast than normal**. It also doesn't expend a spell slot, which means **the ritual version of a spell can't be cast at a higher level.**
>
> To cast a spell as a ritual, a spellcaster must have a feature that grants the ability to do so. **The cleric and the druid, for example, have such a feature. The caster must also have the spell prepared** or on his or her list of spells known, unless the character's ritual feature specifies otherwise, as the wizard's does.

So, we can see that *identify* will be cast at it's lowest level, but it doesn't have any "At Higher Levels" clause, so that makes no difference. You must also have it prepared, but as a Knowledge Domain cleric, it will always be prepared for you.

Furthermore, there is no difference with regards to the spell's effects if it is cast by a cleric vs. a wizard or any other spellcaster class for that matter. The fact that it is a Knowledge Domain cleric casting the spell makes no difference.